# Integração com ZAPIER - Erro Javascript Exception: `body size is too long`

Tags: javascript, integração

Ao tentar recolher os dados do Jasmin com a integração do ZAPIER frequentemente ocorre o erro:
Javascript Exception: `body size is too long`
A ZAPIER diz que o problem tem de ser visto do lado do Jasmin, que é responsável pelo desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmin team member here!
Depois de uma análise junto da equipa Zapier, tivemos de atualizar na nossa integração com a plataforma Zapier o uso da feature [Dehydration](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#dehydration), disponibilizada por eles, e o problema não se verifica mais nos nossos testes.